# How can I configure rollup to include a library only once?

Tags: typescript, build, vite, rollupjs

I am using vite for a Typescript project and am trying to include the axios library only once, not several times, in the production bundle.

The problem is that I have generated sources (several openapi modules) that are listed as dependencies in the package.json and each generated module relies on its own node_modules folder to include axios. However, axios is always exactly the same library.

I am configuring manualChunks for my dependencies and the output format is set to 'es'.
Using the resolve-Plugin ('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve') and include the modules in the 'dedupe' option did not solve this either.
The Rollup Visualizer shows that the axios library is included several times in one chunk.
[Rollup Visualizer for the relevant chunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCH4b.png)

Is there a way to tell rollup that this library is the same, i.e. rollup does not include it several times and can resolve references to it accordingly?